# Registration form in a popup window (colorbox or jQuery ui)?

Tags: 7, users, javascript

How to embed a registration form in a popup window?

I would like to use Colorbox or jQuery UI:

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.dialog');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already a module for that, [Ajax Login/Register](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_register):

> This module provides a smooth way for the user to login, register and request new password via AJAX at any Drupal site.
>
> Features:
>
> - This module provides a block with 2 links (Login, Register) for the anonymous user.
> - When the user clicks on Login or register the requested form appears in a nice ajax popup.
> - The login and register forms can validate using ajax and not redirect on error.
> - On success the module redirects to the user page.
> - When user is logged in, the block provides a Welcome !username message and a link to the user page and a logout link.
> - This module integrates the thickbox plugin with the Ajax module and provides a simple, easy to use and cool login and register block.

Comment: OK its a nice one but how could i do that in a program way? I have a piece of code for drupal 6, but not the 7 one ( Just to do without any additional modules and in my stylish popup as i wish )

Comment: @clive: Ur solution  worked perfectly in my case thanks a lot:)